# Ansible unable to access group_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-ad-hoc

I am not able to access my group_vars.

My current directory where i have my inventory file

```
[ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ pwd
/home/ansible/inventory
```

created group_vars directory in inventory

```
[ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ ls
group_vars  inventory
```

created labservers file inside group_vars

```
[ansible@akashd1c group_vars]$ vi labservers
```

added the variable content

```
[ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ cat group_vars/labservers
opt_dir: /opt
```

Testing using ping  --- it works fine

```
[ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ ansible akashd2c.mylabserver.com -i inventory -m ping
 akashd2c.mylabserver.com | SUCCESS => {
"ansible_facts": {
    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
},
"changed": false,
"ping": "pong"
}
```

Now running using variable - GETTING ERROR

```
[ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ ansible akashd2c.mylabserver.com -i inventory -a "ls -l {{opt_dir}}"
akashd2c.mylabserver.com | FAILED | rc=-1 >>
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'opt_dir' is undefined
```

I tried to change the ansible.cfg inventory log - still wont work.

```
#inventory = /home/ansible/inventory/inventory
```

updated file to yml file

```
[ansible@akashd1c group_vars]$ ls
labservers.yml
[ansible@akashd1c group_vars]$ cat labservers.yml 
 ---
 opt_dir: /opt
```

inventory

```
 [ansible@akashd1c inventory]$ cat inventory 
 akashd2c ansible_host=akashd2c.mylabserver.com
 [labserver]
 akashd2c.mylabserver.com
 akashd3c.mylabserver.com
```

Comment: The group vars file has to be a valid YAML file.

Comment: Your inventory appears to have (based on your `ls`) just the `group_vars` directory. Where is the actual inventory file to assign the server in question to the group `labservers`? And, as @dgw pointed out, it needs to be a valid YAML file, so it should be `labservers.yml` (and really should start with the YAML semaphore: `---` on the first line of the file).

Comment: @dgw i just created a yml file and ran ansible , still getting errors :(

Comment: @gaige i have updated the question i missed earlier and changed my file.

Comment: You have failed to include the actual inventory contents in your question, since if `akashd2c.mylabserver.com` is not a member of `[labservers]` then ansible will have no way of knowing to apply the `group_vars/labservers.yml` to that host

Comment: edited @mdaniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your group in your inventory is `labserver`, but the `group_vars` filename is `labservers.yml`, plural

Change one or the other to match

In the future, you can very easily use `ansible-inventory -i ./inventory --list` to verify what ansible sees with respect to the hosts and their resolved vars:

```
$ echo 'opt_dir: /opt' > inventory/group_vars/labservers.yml
$ ansible-inventory -i ./inventory --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "akashd2c": {
                "ansible_host": "akashd2c.mylabserver.com"
            }
        }

$ echo 'opt_dir: /opt' > inventory/group_vars/labserver.yml
$ ansible-inventory -i ./inventory --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "akashd2c": {
                "ansible_host": "akashd2c.mylabserver.com"
            },
            "akashd2c.mylabserver.com": {
                "opt_dir": "/opt"
```

Comment: I did not realise they are intertwined , i just started learning ansible :)  really appreciate your help.